# freenas change password on console - missing question for old password

Tags: security, password-protection, nas

**The freeNAS_11.3 console allows a too simple password change:**

When starting my **freeNAS** test server (freeNAS 11.3 Rel-p5 r325575),
I'm getting after a while of booting the **option menu** with 11 points
----
1) Configure Network Interfaces
...
**7) Reset Root Password**
...
11) Shut Down
----
With **option 7)** I'm immediately allowed to choose a new password,
without any question for the old password ...

In my opinion that can be a problem in situations where the freeNAS server
is running in a somehow "unsecure" environment.

**Why there is** (at least) **no option** to force
first the **question for the old password**
**before changing to a new password**?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Immutable Laws of IT Security](https://www.marshall.edu/it/departments/information-security/10-immutable-laws-of-security/):

> Law #3: If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it’s not your computer anymore

What you have here is access to the machine directly. No remote interface of any good NAS system will allow a remote user to reset a password without authentication. However, it is assumed that if you have physical access(direct tty, session, etc. on the device - keyboard attached to the physical device) to the machine, you could do all sorts of thing to steal the data. Hence no tight security around the reset-passwort button.

Especially with a NAS, one could just grab the data drives and hook them into a different system to read them. To prevent this, encrypt your data either individually and/or all at once with something like Bitlocker. Then you have to type in your password on each startup, but that data will be encrypted at rest, meaning it'll take an attacker longer to get to your data.